# Use the epsilon-delta approach to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to x} (\sqrt{a+h})=\sqrt{a+x}$

Tags: limits, inequality, solution-verification

I am new to limits and inequalities, so I just wanted to make sure I am correctly employing the formal epsilon-delta definition.

My goal is to demonstrate that:

> $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to x} (\sqrt{a+h})=\sqrt{a+x}$

I will use the following two lemmas:

> $ \vert \sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} \vert \leq \sqrt{ \vert a -b \vert } $

> for $x,y \gt 0$: $\quad x \gt y \leftrightarrow x^2 \gt y^2$

---

Firstly, consider an arbitrary $\epsilon$.

One can easily demonstrate that $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to x}(a+h)=a+x$.

This entails that the following statement is true: $$\lvert a +h - (a+x) \rvert \lt \epsilon^2\ ,$$

where the corresponding $\delta$ is $0 \lt \lvert h-x \rvert \lt \epsilon^2 = \delta$.

Recalling our lemmas, we have:

$$\lvert \sqrt{a+h} - \sqrt{a+x}\rvert \leq \sqrt{\lvert a+h-(a+x) \rvert}$$
and

$$\sqrt{\lvert a+h-(a+x) \rvert} \lt \sqrt{\epsilon^2}$$

But this means that

$$\lvert \sqrt{a+h} - \sqrt{a+x}\rvert \lt \sqrt{\epsilon^2} = \epsilon$$

Further, we can use the same $\delta$ that we previously defined.

---

Does everything check out?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: how can we have  ?$\lvert \sqrt{a+h} - \sqrt{a+x}\rvert \leq \sqrt{\lvert a+h-(a+x) \rvert}$

Comment: @Khosrotash are you asking about the first lemma specifically? Or the application of the first lemma to these particular expressions?

Comment: I ask about inequality ...$\lvert \sqrt{a+h} - \sqrt{a+x}\rvert \leq \sqrt{\lvert a+h-(a+x) \rvert}$

Comment: @Khosrotash ummm, it's just the application of the first lemma. To avoid symbolic overload, I'll rewrite the first lemma as $ \vert \sqrt{c}-\sqrt{d} \vert \leq \sqrt{ \vert c -d \vert } $. Now, set $c=a+h$ and $d=a+x$.

Comment: To be extra diligent you could put an additional constraint on $\delta$ to ensure $a+h\geq 0$.

Comment: Looks good. As an aside: $\lim_{h \to x} f(a + h) = \lim_{h \to (a + x)} f(h)$. These arguments are sometimes simplified with this sort of thing.

Comment: @Ben thank you for the added input! Cheers~

Comment: @S.Cramer Cheers, and welcome to Limits! That's a crafty solution. Your first lemma is interesting. I've not seen that one before. Seems a good one to know.